# Why is the Tkinter render quality much worse on windows?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I have developed a python app with Tkinter on a Mac. It involves forms, and canvas drawings. On the Mac, it looks great. However on my Dell laptop (4K display, and more powerful than my Mac), the Tkinter ui appears very pixelated and certain elements are located slightly differently. What is this problem known as and what can I do to render Tkinter better on Dell Windows 10 or other platforms in general?
Here is a screen shot of the same part of the UI (showing form and canvas drawing)...

**Windows(bad)**
[image]

**Mac(normal)**

[image]

Comment: I have a qhd device , i am having the same issue with my apps , this thing is called scaling. You moved from a lower resolution to a 4k , python should auto scale but it doesn't. You can't do much but you can change your pc resolution to full hd instead of 4k. I starred your question i also want to know a proper solution without lowering my resolution

Comment: A screenshot of the situation may help future users identify themselves (or not) with your situation. Moreover, it may help people here to reproduce your problem.

Comment: updated. cheers.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of 1 or 2 lines being drawn so I can test it on my end. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I may have a work around but I need some code to test with.

Comment: Will You please give us your code, So that we should test.

Comment: The code is basic widgets such as Button(), etc. And a few line and circle canvas drawings. Nothing special.

Comment: You may be running into limitations of the OS. The Windows API won't draw nice anti-aliased lines and shapes like you show in the Mac example.

Comment: Mac using TCL (built-in) but windows can do this performance without full source(Library). Windows used DLL as TCL source, did you know all DLL compiled for your machine ? Need hook graphic card resource if want same quality.

Answer (score 2):

Antialiasing is only enabled for Tkinter canvas object in OSX . You can get the `aggDraw` lib: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-aggdraw.htm as a workaround, but otherwise you will get jagged lines when trying to draw on a canvas. Fonts however should be anti-aliased on all major platforms.

Comment: Even with antialiasing the fonts will look different between Mac and Windows. See https://blog.codinghorror.com/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid/ which also has links to other discussions.

Comment: I agree. The more aggregious problem seems to be the jagged circles and lines though. I assumed that was the problem being asked about, not the fact that the fonts look different.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your DPI awareness to 1 should resolve your issue

```
from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The differences in the display of the same application are due to differences in render engines used by each Operating system.

This is coverd in a Pakt pub ebook called Tkinter GUI Application Development Blueprints

passage regarding this topic available [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=W_qoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=tkinter+windows+vs+mac+render&source=bl&ots=JOksLPdZil&sig=33MS8pZs8DYFZK8aI9eovgSWpwM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg_MPTpOHUAhXH8j4KHXryBVIQ6AEIRjAF#v=onepage&q=tkinter%20windows%20vs%20mac%20render&f=false).

It may be a pain to do but it looks like the most common fix for this is to detect your enviroment and write independent styles using the ***external option database***
more info is available in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#setting-options).

Comment: It's good to have a link to show where you got your quotes, but you should try and pull out the relevant passage into your answer. Otherwise if the link is taken down in future you answer is rendered meaningless.