# how to fix the low quality of tkinter render

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, screen-resolution

On Mac, all widgets and canvas items appear of high quality on Retina display.  However, on Windows 4K display, Tkinter has poor quality, and renders unnecessarily badly (pixelated) as if from 2009.

How do I fix the quality of Tkinter on Windows 10?

I have tried using scaling, but this just makes all sorts of elements all sorts of different sizes.

Comment: Here’s similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887362/why-is-the-tkinter-render-quality-much-worse-on-windows ... but they are both unanswered yet :(

Comment: this issue needs some awareness... the quality is really poor for 4k.

Comment: Could you post the portion of code which renders the objects on screen?

Comment: It's just basic widgets such as Button(), Label(), etc

Answer (score 6):

What I usually do is that I import this module `ctypes` and type in `ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)`. This will make the window of a higher quality.

Hope it works for you!